Edit JSON property file for use in bash script
I have a .sh script and a .json properties file for use with AWS CLI v2 to create a CF Stack.  I have a parameters file in JSON that I need to substitute one value, but all th key/value pairs are the same and I cannot figure out how to get it to pick the right one, the variable MY_ENV in defined in the script and the line below is what I need to pass the edited JSON file into.  I believe it will also take it s a full String Blob instead of file if that is easier.  I was trying jq with no luck but maybe there's an even easier solution
aws cloudformation create-stack --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --stack-name $lambda-$env --template-url <url> --output json --parameter $property_file <-- file I am passing in

property_file
[
  {"ParameterKey":"RuleState", "ParameterValue": "DISABLED"},
  {"ParameterKey":"LambdaSchedule", "ParameterValue":"rate(20 minutes)"},
  {"ParameterKey":"EnvironmentParam", "ParameterValue":"$MY_ENV"}, <-- the string I need changed
  {"ParameterKey":"Method", "ParameterValue":"POST"},
  {"ParameterKey":"LambdaName", "ParameterValue":"TestLambda"}
]


Aside: $ENV is a reserved name -- it changes how POSIX shells initialize themselves. If you want to be 100% certain you aren't unintentionally overwriting an environment variable that impacts system behavior, stick to lowercase names as advised in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

...mind, if you were just trying to refer to an actual environment variable named ENV, that would be "ParameterValue":env.ENV in jq (but again, don't use that name).

It is just a variable named ENV - could be anything.  Will update the question to make it more explicit

"ParameterValue": env.MY_ENV, then, in your jq code (assuming your property file can be written as jq source code rather than as a JSON document; --parameter <(jq -n "$property_file") is the easiest way to do this).

envsubst < parameters.file may achieve what you wanted.

Or envsubst '$MY_ENV' < "$property_file" if replacement should be restricted to $MY_ENV.

If you map over the outer array, select the item where .ParameterKey == "EnvironmentParam", and set .ParameterValue = env.MY_ENV.
map(select(.ParameterKey == "EnvironmentParam").ParameterValue = env.MY_ENV)

To import the name (not the value of) MY_ENV from the shell, use the --arg flag:
jq --arg e MY_ENV 'map(select(…).ParameterValue = env[$e])'


So how would I use this as command argument though?

You could redirect jq's output into a file using jq … > filename, and then reference that as in --parameter filename, or do all of that inline using process substitution as in --parameter <(jq …).

Giving you credit for a good answer - but end of the day I just used sed

Be careful though, as with a text-based (ie. not JSON-aware) solution (like with sed or envsubst) you may run into issues if the search pattern inadvertently matches other content, including structure components, possibly also invalidating the JSON encoding, which jq (or any other JSON processor) would automatically take care of.
